# Systray bubble not showing up (with enabled baloons in XP)

Tags: c#, winforms, systray

I was wondering what is wrong and after searching here I found out it could be due to disabled balloons, but thats not my case.
I am using simple code, but it doesnt work. Thank you

```
    NotifyIcon ntf = new NotifyIcon();
    ntf.BalloonTipText="bla";
    ntf.Visible=true;
    ntf.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add Icon too

```
NotifyIcon ntf = new NotifyIcon();
ntf.BalloonTipText="bla";
ntf.Visible=true;
ntf.Icon = new Icon("myApp.ico");
ntf.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
```

Comment: I tried this too. I have this code as part of an event for a button. The balloon tip doesn't appear. Does anyone have any other suggestions why? I have provided a balloon tip text, title, icon and set it's visible property to true.